# Is it possible to retrieve Job ID generated by sfdx:force:mdapi:deploy -c flag so as to use that Job ID in next step using -q flag to actual deploy

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli

I have jenkins pipeline with SFDX CLI integration. I have few stages in pipeline like login, validate.

In validate I have SFDX command

`rc = command "${toolbelt}/sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -f unpackaged.zip -u ${USERNAME} -w 180 -l ${TestLevel} -c"`

where -c is used to only validate the deployment.

Now, I have a requirement where if validate is completed / successful then I need to deploy that change set into target Salesforce org. So, according to sfdx:force:mdapi:deploy documentation there is option to quick deploy with flag -q. But for that I will need the **Job ID** of the validated change set. So I am confused how to retrieve **Job ID** from validate step and use it in quick deploy step so as to it will first validate and deploy the change set.

Note: I am new to Salesforce deployment so let me know if I am not following standard process for change set deployment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `--json` so that you can obtain the deployment `Id` as needed by the other command.

Something like below

```
rc = command "${toolbelt}/sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -f unpackaged.zip -u ${USERNAME} -w 180 -l ${TestLevel} -c --json"
```

The deployment result will be JSON now as below

```
{
 "status": 0,
 "result": {
  ...
   "id": "0Af80000003ynf6CAA",
   "status": "Succeeded",
   "success": true
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I will need to store this JSON output to a file to access in next SFDX CLI commands  ? Like, how it will be available to use by other command in next stages of Jenkins pipeline ?